# Why does my web page not load properly from behind the firewall?

Tags: firewall, azure, web-server, openvpn, nat

I am setting up OpenVPN Access server on Ubuntu 18.04 behind a Microsoft Azure Firewall, for our developers to tunnel in and connect to their developer test environments.  Having the VPN server behind the firewall is a hard requirement from our IT department.

My background:

- My Linux, OpenVPN admin, network admin and web admin and development skills are rusty, at best.

My setup:

- OpenVPN Access Server on Ubuntu 18.04 VM (as mentioned above)
- Azure Firewall (as mentioned above)
- OpenVPN Access Server VM is on its own subnet.
- OpenVPN Access Server does **not** have a public IP. I am NAT'ing all
  traffic on ports 443, 943 and 1194 to OpenVPN server private IP.
- Azure Firewall Network Rules allow inbound and outbound traffic to and from OpenVPN
  server/subnet.
- NAT and Network Rules limit access to machines from my network.
- Application Rules allow outbound access to asb.sts.openvpn.net, per
  troubleshooting guide on OpenVPN website (website calls for "direct
  access" to this FQDN).
- Routes implemented between firewall and vpn subnets, in both
  directions.
- DNS is enabled on Azure Firewall, DNS pointing to Google (8.8.8.8 and
  8.8.4.4).
- Timeout on OpenVPN server is set to 5 minutes.
- OpenVPN server uses Twisted web server (came with the OpenVPN solution
  in Azure)

Failure Mode:
Admin login page at https://x.x.x.x:943/admin loads.  Sometimes the web page is complete with images and correct layout, sometimes not.  There is no pattern to what will load properly and what will not.
I log in, my credentials are accepted, and I am either redirected back to login page, or I am redirected to EULA page (I am always forced to agree to EULA).  I agree to EULA, and sometimes I will be directed to admin web page, sometimes I am redirected back to the login page (with various things not loaded).  On those rare occasions I am directed to the admin web page, and when the page loads enough controls for me to perform a function, clicking on a control brings me back to the login page, where etc.

Things I have tried:
Restarting OpenVPN server/vm.
Adding and removing various rules on my firewall.
Checked the OpenVPN server log.  No apparent error.
Inspected the various web pages in Chrome:
[image]

I am trying to troubleshoot this while at the same time building/rebuilding my skills.  I am stuck.  Any pointers/next steps would be greatly appreciated. A whack on the side to get things unstuck wouldn't hurt either.  Thanks.

UPDATE:  I have met the enemy and he is me.  I've narrowed down the problem to my NAT'ing, but not sure what's going on.  From inside the firewall, the OpenVPN admin experience is nominal.  Also, if my OpenVPN server has a separate public IP, the experience is as I would expect.  It's something I'm doing, or not, with NAT'ing, firewall network rules, or routing.  That's not really narrowing it down, but I can confirm the problem is not with the OpenVPN server.  So, I've changed the title of this question.

Comment: Why pay $900 a month for a firewall when you can buy a standard sku vpn for $3.25 a month?

Comment: Not an option.  Thanks for your input.